# Chemistry site design

Tags: discussion, design

I’m Kurtis, senior product designer at Stack Exchange. First, I wanted to congratulate you because this site is now starting the process of moving out of beta to become a fully-graduated site! Well done!

## Graduation and Your Site Design

Graduation comes with a few perks. We have already started your site's design, which will be a reflection of the chemistry site's subject and culture. This will help brand your site as unique, even while you share common elements with other sites as part a bigger Stack Exchange family.

Once the design goes up, you will receive a link in the footer of other sites in the network, along with the ability to migrate content to and from other sites — and the notoriety of a public launch that says, "Congratulations, you finally made it!"

**Design Concept**

For our Chemistry's site design and branding, We wanted to have use the community's ideas and come up with a way to show both the theoretical and a applied sides of chemistry. We also look for inspiration that was simple, scientific, and academic. We've gathered some artwork we found online for setting up a mood board.

**Mood Board**

[image: Mood board]

**Color scheme**

Overall, we wanted the site to have a clean lab like feel with a splash of bright colors in the header.

[image: Color scheme]

**Logo**

For the logo we were looking for a balance between an accurate representation of a molecule and a unique symbol that represents this community. Based on community suggestions [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/605/13146) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/494/13146), we decided to focus on the benzene molecule because of it's simple hexagonal shape and aromatic hydrocarbon configuration. We started by exploring different ways we could make an icon that would be simple enough to scale to a very small size and still remain recognizable. At the top of the image below are a few early iterations.

[image: logo explorations]

At the bottom of the image above is where we landed. OK, before you say "but all five carbon atoms should be the same color", read on — the different colors are intentional as they represent the diversity of all the Chemistry site users from different backgrounds and locations. And the delocalized structure of electrons in benzene is symbolic of the exchange of ideas. So if you were out wearing a t-shirt with the logo and someone were to point out the color, you would then have an entry point into a conversation about the site.

**Sample Site Illustrations**

[image: sample illustrations]

**Swag**

[image: example swag]

Stickers / coffee mug / t-shirt

**Overall site design**

Click image to view full-sized version.

[image]
[image]

We considered a few different options for the site's font given that this community uses a lot of MathJax. Finally, we decided to stick with a sans-serif font that has a similar x-height to the MathJax font — this way the equations stand out but don't look too different from the surrounding text.

After we receive and implement the community's feedback, we're just a few steps from finalizing all of the assets and publishing your new design!

Comment: This. Is. The. Best. Piece. Of. News. I've. Heard. Here. AWESOME!

Comment: Okay. So now, as `imgur` is filtered in some countries, I was wondering if you would mind my changing the image links to `i.stack.imgur`.

Comment: @MARamezani I had no idea about this. Can you see images in the posts, just not the larger site images?

Comment: Kurtis I can't see the images that are `i.imgur`, but I can see the images that are `i.stack.imgur`. For example, I can't see the image for **mood board**.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @MARamezani that should do it. The larger versions of the site are still on i.imgur because of file sizes, but everything else has been migrated.

Comment: [Tanks!](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3atanks)

Comment: This feels very rewarding for me as a regular contributor to this site. I think that a big applause for the "core" contributors is well deserved, especially Ron, Martin and Klaus (and many others of course!)

Comment: This looks amazing, @KurtisBeavers.  I can't wait.

Comment: I love this so much! :D

Comment: These designs look great! You've done a brilliant job!

Comment: What's the timescale we're looking at before the site is migrated/updated?

Comment: @AriBenCanaan we usually give the community about a week to give all of their feedback and then we begin to finish all the assets. It shouldn't be too long before things are live unless there are major revisions to the design that need to happen.

Comment: you have +100. good ;)

Comment: I can't wait for this the design look so cleaner and all. The benzene logo represents what the stack exchange chemistry all about.

Comment: I also like the badge, it has some texture

Comment: @Simon-Nail-It They are in form of beakers. Similar to what I had suggested [Here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/501/5456) or exactly what alpha have suggested there  :D

Comment: I guess this is the way I was expecting this graduation theme to be. It's brilliant!

Comment: @Alpha thank you. This has been a wonderful community to work with.

Answer (score 21):

I like the overall design, the logo is recognizable without being too cliché. But there is one aspect that bothers me a bit, though it might be rather pedantic.

The flasks and reaction apparatuses in the header don't really make sense. The individual flasks or containers are fine, but the combinations are not anything that you would see in a lab or that could work at all. I think there might be enough real glassware combinations to fill the header, so that we don't have to rely on implausible ones.

A standard reaction apparatus in organic chemistry would be something like the following:

[image]

A round-bottom flask with a condenser on top of it, heated by an oil bath (but you could just use a bunsen burner, as they already exist in the header). The total height might be a problem.

[image]

A distillation bridge like this is also very recognizable.

Comment: Thanks. We could easily and happily revise some of the glassware combinations.

Answer (score 16):

Overall, I ***really*** like the design. Certainly "benzene" speaks chemistry and I like the logo on swag. :-)

I also think the water-like vote buttons is a great touch.

No one has commented, but I really like the molecules in the background of the header. My initial response was also "wow, that's way too much glassware" but having the molecules in the background is wonderful.

Just to be pedantic, but could you post a high-resolution version of the green background. I think it would be good to "proofread" the chemical structures and make sure there isn't anything subtly wrong.

I helped with an art project where they etched chemical structures into a stone picnic table and there were several "typos."

Some minor nitpicky things with the glassware:
[image]

The big blue-filled flask on the left should *not* have so much stuff in it. It's unsafe. You shouldn't heat anything that's more than half-filled (and better ~1/3). I'd also guess something will shoot out the side neck. You'd make me really happy if you could add a little tube condenser like a [Graham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condenser_(laboratory)#Graham_condenser) or Allihn condenser on the top. Bonus, I think they look cool.

The apparatus on the right should have the test tube pointing diagonally "up" rather than down and to the right. It's clearly unsafe to heat a tube like this and it's not clear why you'd set it up like this.

These are *really* minor points, but I'm assuming you'd like us to make sure the design makes sense. If you can post a high-res or retina version of the green background, I'd be happy to check it too.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. If you click on the image of the site designs, you'll get a higher resolution version.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I clicked on the images, but the background is still very blurry, possibly because of JPG compression. Would it be possible to publish a retina PNG somewhere? I can't make out enough of the chemical structures to proofread. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/H4yeTe7.png

Comment: Is it possible to get just the green background? That image still looks really blurry. I have a hard time making out some of the fine details. http://i.imgur.com/pDeprDA.png

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to read that background. It's a subtle detail (like old equations that have been erased from a chalkboard.) If it was clear enough to read, it would be distracting from the actual content of the site.

Comment: I'm really wondering why this was downvoted.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Ok, but I'm wondering whether it's worth checking the non-blurred background. I like the concept, but hey, it's the Internet and if there's a typo, someone will find it eventually... why not now?

Comment: Oh, alright: http://i.imgur.com/cJmsHHU.png

Comment: I agree. Proofreading would be good. I have not even noticed the obvious safety flaws in the design, good catch!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jAT7E7v.png OK, I see one issue, one incredibly minor thing and one "huh, what is that". On the left, there's a double bond from the triangle to the H. It should be http://i.imgur.com/WaV1SCc.png

Comment: The circled piece on the very right looks like it should have an "O" where there's an empty space, but when it's "erased" and blurred, it's no issue.

Comment: The "what is that" in the middle is the cube-like thing. Otherwise, it's all correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Kurtis I see problems with the iodine fluoride. Have a look at the structure posted by ron here:http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/29142/4945 there are too many dots in the one in the background, let me try to put that in graphics

Comment: @Martin I'm glad I have you and Geoff as editors :)

Comment: @Kurtis realised, that the graphic in rons post is different, it is $\ce{IF7}$ not $\ce{IF5}$, here is the corresponding [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_pentafluoride). I cut the dots that were too much here http://imgur.com/Aywfxcz (I hope that works...)

Comment: @Kurtis And thank you for the honorable mention :D If you could squeeze in the fourth structure as well and arrange them like in this post http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/21858/4945, that would we awesome. Thanks a lot for your concern! And your work, It looks great!

Comment: @Martin Will do. I think the feedback is fairly straight-forward. We were waiting to see if any other major concern with the design come in, but will likely begin to finish the site conversion in the next few day (if everything else goes to plan. It could be next week that it goes live.)

Answer (score 13):

Well, it looks very bright and colourful, just like chemistry is. Mostly green I guess. Well done on the text part of the logo (), implementing the tube as the "I" looks very neat. The benzene ... it is a different story. The overall arc, I think I like or at least get used to.

---

However, I have a few questions:

I don't know if it is the compression of the screenshot or not, but the links in the banner look very fuzzy to me, maybe bold is not the best choice here. The chemistry logo looks much cleaner in comparison.

[image: fuzzy, not pretty]

Related to this, it seems a little odd, that the banner "hangs over" at the sides - is that intentional?

---

I can appreciate the effort with the font, it looks a bit better now, as it is closer to the formulas. I personally find the bolder font set harder to read. But I also find sans serif fonts hard to read in general.

[image: font stuff]

Hence, I would prefer, something that is better to read, like in journals, where formula and text blends into each other:

[image: jacs screenshot]

Is there a particular reason, why you stick to a sans serif font? Compare [Can we have a font that harmonizes with inline MathJAX?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/592/4945)

Comment: Fonts—In print a serif font for body copy is usually easier to read because the serif ad hints to the letter shapes. On screen it's a bit different because of the lower resolution of screens, the tiny serifs become blocky and distorted. This is less so with retina displays, but there are still a lot of people who don't have retina displays. Some of this is preference. I find serif fonts on screen in large quantities of serif fonts on screen to be difficult to read unless I'm on my retina display or the font size is very large.

Comment: Banner—The overhang was just to provide a surface for the glassware to sit on.

Comment: Navigation—The screenshot distorted a bit when it was compressed to fit the file size limit. The live version will be sharper.

Comment: @Kurtis thanks for the reply. I just wondered, as they have serif fonts on math.se and it really looks quite good. But yeah all in all, I would say good job. Good to hear that the navigation will look sharper.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the feedback! We're open to considering serif fonts if the community feels strongly about it.

Comment: I'd give +1 to a serif font. Granted, I use a retina screen, but I think there's support for harmonizing with MathJax.

Comment: +1 for serif fonts! I use the cheapest screen I can get, and I can refer serif just fine. I prefer to be able to tell the difference between I, l, 1, and |, especially the first two.

Comment: I am all for serif fonts, especially in the body part of questions and answers. The comments might stay sans-serif, not only because they are smaller and as such might make for harder reading with serifs, but also to visually enhance the difference between comment and content.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Um, what's with the badge colors?

[image]

Could we replace the color codes for bronze and gold badges?

Comment: Yeah, they're mistakenly reversed in the design comp. That's an easy fix.

Comment: Haha, then I think I should delete this. But wait, should I do it after you correct the "typo"?

Comment: It's updated. You can delete this post if you'd like. Tanks.

Answer (score 2):

This post is for THANKING design team to consider our [suggestions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/can-site-users-suggest-some-design-specifications-regarding-graduated-site-devel/501#501).

Badges are as Suggested by Alpha and Freddy(that's me).

I have remember someone suggested Benzene.

Though "Accept Answer" idea suggested by John Snow [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/503/5456) was not considered. Is it possible to keep that burner?

Thanks once again :)

Comment: Misspelling - It should be *tanking*...

Comment: No, thank you! I like John Snow's idea, but whatever icon we use needs to at the very least be in the shape of a checkmark—this is a user interface convention that we try to keep consistent from site to site. I'm not sure I understand if the burner can fit this criteria.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Yes there should be consistency, I agree.

Comment: The check mark is in the flame. I know that would be hard to show in the list formatting so I wouldn't expect it to be used, but i do appreciate the consideration.

Comment: Yes there is checkmark but it should be overall in shape of a checkmark. @JohnSnow

Answer (score 2):

I like it, green isn't my thing, but it's nice there. However it my be my opinion but isn't benzene a bit cliche? I mean, its not a test tube (*that would make a terribly cliche logo*) but could we have a logo closer to [www.chemicalize.org](http://www.chemicalize.org/)'s logo, a visually appealing chemical that isn't Benzene? Naphthalene is nice, and pyrrole would work. But other wise it's nice. Hope this didn't seem like a rant on the evils of the cliche benzene.

Comment: Meh. We're only overcomplicating things if use a molecule less popular than the ol' benzene. Why would it be a cliche?

Comment: @MARamezani because benzene is always used in association with chemistry sites.

Comment: Frequency in using something doesn't mean it's a cliche. It's only a cliche **when repeatedly seeing it is annoying and monotonously unexciting.** Dunno, but it seems this isn't true for many folks here.

Comment: Well, it is true for me. It is not as cliche as the jelly benzene, but very close. But then again it should be recognisable for all audiences, so I think it is a good choice. I also believe, we are way past the point where this complaint will have any effect.