# Site graduated! New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/chemistry-site-design).

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

We have also updated the site's [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackchemistry) profile and [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) themes. Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Wow! I was surprised in the middle of writing an answer. This is amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: There has been dancing in the streets here.... well, I was dancing in the streets until a traffic warden reminded me that a) I was still in my pyjamas and b) I was a traffic hazard.

Comment: The most pleasant surprise! Thank you! **Especially** for making the text more similar to the chemical formula text. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: Chatroom theme update is up. Please let me know if there are any tweaks to be made. It's my first time and I'm a <s>doctor, not an escalator</s> developer, not a designer. :)

Comment: Well the test tubes and other instruments look really cool even in upvote buttons and badges! Really awesome redesign!

Comment: Yay! It's been a great journey so far and it's awesome to see Chemistry reaching its next milestone!

Comment: I like the badges so much. At least it's not circle or triangle

Comment: I discovered that the meta site changed color

Comment: I love love love it!

Comment: I love the arrows.

Comment: Kay Mr.Beavers as suggested by Martin, I'll leave a [link to my design change request](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/design-request-can-i-please-have-the-visited-questions-in-a-different-color) here.

Answer (score 34):

Thank you to everyone that has made this graduation possible.

### For all of the avid askers, answerers, editors, voters, flaggers, etc., my hat's off to you.

For the especially avid members (you know who you are), we literally could not have done this without you!

---

<sup><sup><sup>Not making any promises, but there may be some rewards to be had at some point.  If not, I will fight for them.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Setting zoom factor to 200% - ah, yes, now I can read ;)

Comment: I nominate @Martin-マーチン for the 'our favorite member' award.  And by 'our' I mean 'mine' but I'm certain there are others who feel the same.

Comment: @LordStryker Well, perhaps there can be a vote on that soon. :-)

Comment: I would love at least stickers or other promotional material. If I had enough, I'd be happy to post them around ACS meetings, etc.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Easter egg in Avogadro 2?  Maybe?? Yeah?!?!

Comment: Awww, thank you @LordStryker. I feel very honoured. :D

Comment: @Geoff Kurtis teased us with "swag" in his initial presentation. I guess this could be happening ;) See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ojLLj.png).

Answer (score 16):

Something else needs to be mentioned - kudos to our moderators!

In no particular order (other than alphabetical):

[F'x](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/30/fx), [jonsca](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/73/jonsca) and [ManishEarth](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/22/manishearth)

Comment: Thanks :) Wouldn't have been possible without our very active community members!

Comment: Thank you for those kind wishes!

Answer (score 13):

I came to a beta site yesterday to ask my first question.

I came somewhere else to receive my answer.

And the *somewhere else*  is AWESOME!

Maybe my good question forced the system to launch this site ;)

**Congratulations to everyone who put up a good job in the development and designing of this site.**

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to say that I'm really, *really* happy to have had my small part in making Chemistry.SE what it is today. During my time here I've learned an **amazing** amount, interacted with some great people, and had fun trying to help whomever I could to the best of my ability. It's been one of my most rewarding experiences ever. When I look back at the day I joined two years ago, after coming home from a tiring shift in the lab but still deciding to join and spend an hour writing an answer, I'm very glad my past self put in the effort and took that first step.

Pride is something I rarely experience, but being here for this graduation definitely makes me feel proud. It means a lot.

Thank you so much, everyone!

Comment: I have to disagree with one thing you said:  "small".  It's people like you who've made this whole crazy thing work.  you *should* feel proud.  Keep it up.  You're making a difference to an incredible number of people.

Comment: "small"?  You are a Chemistry-deity!

Answer (score 5):

Yohooo!! Yeah!!! ....wait..... did I just miss the GRADUATION??

Congratulations to the community for this wonderful acheivement and a special thanks to the moderators.

The site design is amazing! It feels great to be a part of this community.

P.S. *I know I am late but I couldn't go ahead without posting this :)*