# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

Congratulations on [receiving a new design](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/site-graduated-new-design-launched)! Included with your new design is the Community Promotion Ads system. For those who are unfamiliar with how this works, please read onwards!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting chemistry research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2696).

Comment: Are related stack exchange sites eligible for Ads? For example, [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Comment: They're eligible, yes. Your community would be the ones determining if that's what you actually want to steer readers to, though.

Comment: @Molx biology might be a good site to advertise, but I think they'd need to come up with the graphic for us. We're not designers. :-)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I did Physics (because it was easier, there was already a logo and styled site name), but I'll give a try to Biology later. They are close to graduation too, and there are some posts about the possible/future design.

Comment: Never mind.  I think I see. What should the title of he question be? And do I ask it on Chemistry or Chemistry-meta?

Answer (score 21):

[image: Visit our meta site]

Comment: Cool. Great idea!

Comment: @Geoff Thanks, I borrowed the idea from Tex.ex, I'd link to it but I am on mobile right now.

Comment: It's [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5888).

Answer (score 17):

[image: Avogadro - the open molecular editor]

Comment: If this seems self-serving, I'll certainly take it down. I'm mainly posting because there are clearly users here.

Comment: Congratulations on making it into the rotation ;) It is good to know we can have your support here on the network.

Comment: Where is Avogadro 2?  WHERE IS IT?!!

Comment: I use it all the time for my molecular modelling work.  I use it for building GAMESS (US) input files and for analysing the results.  Fantastic software.

Comment: is it possible to add/document explicitly 1) console visualisation interface and 2) read/write of camera position/orientation in ctrl-c/ctrl-v friendly way ?

Comment: @permeakra If you have feature requests, please add issues to GitHub and/or e-mail the mailing list? It's hard to track feature requests on other websites. :-)

Comment: Add it as a new answer to the [2016](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3079/) post, please.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Physics on Stack Exchange]

Comment: Quick note: I didn't draw any of this, just used the website logo and the sticker image from [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/physics-swag-for-top-users).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: What is the font there? I like that a lot.

Comment: I have no idea, honestly.

Comment: [What the font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=H&ch%5B1%5D=&ch%5B2%5D=e&ch%5B3%5D=&ch%5B4%5D=F&ch%5B5%5D=&ch%5B6%5D=&ch%5B7%5D=t&ch%5B8%5D=&ch%5B9%5D=o&ch%5B10%5D=s&ch%5B11%5D=w&ch%5B12%5D=c&ch%5B13%5D=u&ch%5B14%5D=o&ch%5B15%5D=s&ch%5B16%5D=m&ch%5B17%5D=o&ch%5B18%5D=m&ch%5B19%5D=n&ch%5B20%5D=u&ch%5B21%5D=n&ch%5B22%5D=t&ch%5B23%5D=i&ch%5B24%5D=w&ch%5B25%5D=&ch%5B26%5D=t&ch%5B27%5D=t&ch%5B28%5D=&ch%5B29%5D=e&ch%5B30%5D=r&ch%5B31%5D=o&ch%5B32%5D=r&ch%5B33%5D=&ch%5B34%5D=w&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=002350ae54d4d8730006d8cf00000612&glyphcount=35&imageid=0&x=79&y=45) does not have

Comment: @Martin-マーチン It's twitter font.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Current Chemistry Stack Exchange bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: For what it's worth, the trick is to post first to imgur and then to edit the post to link to the dynamic ad.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen that on the main page appearing yet?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison: The size is _not_ a problem.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Biology on Stack Exchange]

Comment: Again, just working with the proposed [Biology Site Design](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community). Once the design is launched, it might be a good idea to update this to fit the final logo/background.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Yeah, and I agree with them. I added the background because the picture would look too empty otherwise, but an update is a must. Shouldn't take too long though, so I'll keep an eye open.

Comment: Since they graduated a couple of hours ago, maybe now is a good time to update this.

Comment: Updated with the new background and better versions of the logo/name.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Detexify²]

Answer (score 9):

[image: If you want down-to-earth answers to your questions]

Answer (score 7):

[image: HSM]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Comment: Taken from http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6505/7433 . Not sure if the community will want it -- so vote away!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Retraction watch]

Comment: Copied from http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1483/21869

Comment: I don't know what this is, and at the moment I get an error opening the link `This webpage has a redirect loop 

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` :(

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Not sure about the redirects. It's a blog that tracks academic article retractions, particularly in the sciences (e.g., some of the recent JACS cases).

Comment: Interesting, it did work now, so I know at least what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Visit Health StackExchange]

Comment: Did you read "How does it work" of the question? This will be ignored in its current format.

Comment: If you want to add the attribution, do so in the comments. Btw, I found the CC link broken.

Comment: © [Tim](http://stackexchange.com/users/3203697/tim) 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: This image is too big.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites). They are supported.

Answer (score 6):

[image: MathJax buttons on text editor]

Comment: Based on the same ad on [Physics SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6393/83101). I'm not 100% satisfied with the final result, suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Taken from http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6401/7433 . Not sure if the community will want it -- so vote away!

Comment: Huh, when did this get the downvotes? I wondered why it disappeared from the ads.

Answer (score 5):

[image: The Molecule Calculator]

Comment: I think this would be a very useful tool anyone participating in the forum.  I have referred to it on numerous occasions in my answers.  Disclaimer I am one of the developers

Answer (score 4):

[image: Important recent papers in computational and theoretical chemistry]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Proposal for Science Educators SE]

Comment: @Tyberius, this looks like something we can easily make!

Comment: did you make this yourself, or was it a screenshot? I would like to promote [this](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGQ0ZDZjMTVjMjg4ZTI1NGY3NzZlNjY5YzQ4Njk1YzJmYjQxOWU1MjNhNzhiZDU3YmJlZDJmMmQ0ZWFjN2MzMfxSPbk7oTRBwbUior7L6VtZ3FgZpg0E5T3gXU1dGr6X0) proposal, but I can't find an image like this anywhere.

Comment: @user1271772: Going by the source, I would guess screenshot, but then I think I can remember that it was somewhat dynamic. Anyway, it was more than four years ago and a lot of things happened since then.

Comment: Thank you @Wrzlprmft. Since you are so active on the physics and mathematics SEs, would you considering committing to my Area51 proposal in my previous comment?

Comment: @user1271772: No. I have no expertise or particular interest in that area whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Your daily fix of Computational Chemistry news]

Answer (score -1):

[image: New site for researches interested in structure determination]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/91841.png))</sub>